# Ошибка каста при сборке Shiboken

Tags: c++, python, mingw, pyside

При установке Shiboken (как отдельно от PySide так и с ним) из под `pip` возникает ошибка компиляции. Текст ошибки:

```
C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-l7ifih_w\Shiboken\sources\shiboken\libshiboken\basewrapper.cpp:773:45: error: cast from 'PyObject* {aka _object*}' to 'Py_hash_t {aka int}' loses precision [-fpermissive]
     return reinterpret_cast<Py_hash_t>(pyObj);
                                             ^
error: Error compiling shiboken
```

Команда установки:

```
pip install --global-option="--make-spec=mingw" PySide (или Shiboken)
```

Используются:
`Python 3.4; MinGW-w64 (gcc 4.9.3); CMake 3.7.0`

Как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему, проблема в том, что указатель 64-битный, а `int` - 32-битный. Самым простым способом может оказаться замена синонима типа `Py_hash_t` с `int` на какой-нибудь `int64_t`.  Но будет ли этот способ правильным, не ясно. Ответ на этот вопрос правильнее искать у службы поддержки *Shiboken*.

Comment: Я снёс MinGW64 и вновь установил обычный, ошибка исчезла, правда собираться проект так и не стал (не может найти один файл). Судя по всему ваше предположение полностью верно. Попытаюсь исправить, спасибо)

Comment: Я задавал аналогичный вопрос на основном стаке, можешь выложить свой ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40523607/installing-shiboken-pyside-with-mingw-w64